# Two (easy?) Android/Java syntax questions

Tags: java, c#, android

I just switched from Xamarin/C# to Android Studio/Java and am familiarizing myself with the dissimilarities between the two languages. I'm reading an android book written in java and came across the following two lines of code:

1)

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
  .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferencesChangeListener);
```

In the first line, i'm confused by how preferencesChangeListener is used. In C# you can't just toss a new preferencesChangeListener object into an argument without instantiating the object. So in Java, are you allowed to implicitly instantiate?

2)

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
  Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
```

Secondly, I am confused by the '&' symbol used here. I thought the ampersand was used for boolean arguments, yet you see here that the left side of the equality is expecting an integer. What's going on here?

Comment: `preferencesChangeListener` would have to be declared in some scope available at the time of that method call. The `&` is a bitwise AND operator in Java when working on numbers

Comment: It looks like `preferenceChangeListener` is a variable reference to an object instance. Is there no prior declaration? `PreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener = new PreferenceChangeListener()` or something similar?

Comment: @Kon You mean bitwise, && is the logical AND operator

Comment: #1: `getDefaultSharedPreferences` is a method that returns an object.  Unless it returns `null`, someone has to instantiate it, somewhere.  Whatever that object is, that object's `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` method is called.  `preferencesChangeListener` is presumably an object that was instantiated earlier.  I don't really understand what "implicit instantiation" is going on here.  This syntax means exactly the same in Java as in C#, I think.  #2: Bit-wise "and".

Comment: @Natecat Yes, good catch

Comment: One other thought on the `preferenceChangeListener` it could be passed in as a null reference that gets set within the `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` method, however normally in a situation like that the parameter should, but is not required to, be defined as an `out` parameter.

Comment: Please make sure to ask one question per post and provide good titles (otherwise question is too broad). Note that knowing list of basic operators for language you are trying to use is expected knowledge on SO and may lead to downvotes due to demonstrated lack of research (I've provided one as an example what may happen).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The 'too broad' rule doesn't say anything about compound questions. It is for questions that are actually too broad for this site, and this question does not fall in that category imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you are not allowed to implicitly instantiate, and if that variable isn't instantiated then you will likely get a `NullPointerException`, unless the method you are calling it is using it as an output
2. In most languages, including java, `&&` is the boolean operator and `&` is the bitwise operator. `&` is a bitwise AND, so for example `(0101) & (1110)` would be `(0100)`. In your example, it is being used to zero out certain bits.